# Create dynamic Express JS middleware based on request's params

Tags: node.js, express

I want to map middleware for express.js dynamically based on it's request param. For instance

```
req.params.appName == 'A' then middleware is A
req.params.appName == 'B' then middleware is B
```

(A and B are functions and they are loaded dynamically via require )
All of them must be setted in runtime without any preset.
I did try some code but it is not work

```
var middleware = [];
router.get('/:appName', function(req, res, next) {
    var appName = req.params.appName;
    var utilsApp = global[appName];
    middleware = [utilsApp];
    console.log(middleware);
    next()
}, middleware);
```

System return 404
Could some one help me please.. Best thank in Advance